# How to convert data datetime from database?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have data I get from database, it’s like this:

[image: datetime from database]

I want to convert it to datetime because it cannot be comparing to other variabel with time value, and it cannot because there a character and other object follow there.

This is error:

[image: error datetime]

How to get just its datetime and don’t make it the other object follow on value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take value as $items[0]->batasbayar or if its in loop : foreach($items as $item){ $item->batasbayer  }. And try converting $item->batasbayer

Answer (score 1):

Use casting on your model. In this way laravel automaticlly convert attribute to expected type if it is possible.

```php
// Your model class
class Booking {

    protected $casts = [
         'batasbayer' => 'datetime'
    ];

}
```

You may find other casts [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

Answer (score 0):

When you want a Model field to be retrieve as a `Carbon` instance you can add it to the `protected $dates`  property of That Model

> This is deprecated in Laravel 8

The recommended way is to pass that field name in the `$casts` property and specify the type in which you want to cast that field.

```
protected $casts = [
     'batasbayer' => 'datetime'
];
```